# force close while adding to array

Tags: java, android, arrays, sqlite

I want to get one column from my SQLite database and add that information in an array.
I use `from array` and `cursor` and two java classes.
My sqlite database doesn't have a problem as in another page I was able to get information.
My Android application force closes while I'm expecting to see the information displayed.

My method (displayrooidad):

```
 public String displayrooidad(int row) {
    Cursor cu = db.query(DB_TBL_ROOIDAD, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    cu.moveToPosition(row);
    String content = cu.getString(1);
    return content;
}
```

my java class
SQLiteHelper: is a javaclass for connect to database.
open and close methods Working properly.

```
public class Rooidad extends AppCompatActivity {
    Spinner sp;
    TextView txt;
    SQLiteHelper sq;
    String[] myarray;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.rooidad);
       // sp=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.sp);
        txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.test);
        sq=new SQLiteHelper(getBaseContext());
        sq.open();
        int row =sq.countofrow();
        myarray=new String[row];
        for(int teller=0;teller<=row;teller++){
            String tittle = sq.displayrooidad(teller);
            myarray[teller]=tittle.toString();
        }
        sq.close();
        txt.setText(myarray[4].toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: please post your `logcat`.

Comment: I edited your post to improve the grammar but I am not sure about the sentence between the two code blocks, can you clarify it a bit?

Comment: @Nathan Thank you.I changed my Sentence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to put `teller < row` because your `tab` has only `row` elements not `row+1`.

Comment: Thank you very much .fixed I deleted "="

Comment: @M.borjian If that fixed your problem, you can accept the answer :)